# True or false: every non-zero vector is parallel to a unit vector

Tags: vectors

The correct answer is True but I don't understand how this is.

How about a vector of value 2? This is a non-zero vector. How can this be parallel to a unit vector?

The explanation I'm given:

"Remember that two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are parallel if 
$$\vec a = \lambda \vec b$$
for some scalar $\lambda$.

Also remember that 
$|\lambda \vec a| = |\lambda||\vec a| $.

So given a vector $\vec a$, what value of $\lambda$ will give a vector $\vec b = \lambda \vec a$ which has magnitude $1$?

The correct answer is 'True'."

Comment: Try to look it the other way: if $\mathbf{a}$ is a unit vector, and $\mathbf{b}$ is the zero vector, what value of $\lambda$ do you need such that $\mathbf{b}=\lambda\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: If you scale a vector by a positive constant, the length scales accordingly. So for example, if a vector has length $3$, scaling it by a factor of  _____ will yield a unit vector in the same direction.

Comment: So a unit vector can have any gradient?

Comment: What do you mean by "a vector of value 2"? (And what do you mean by "gradient"? It is true that for any direction there is a unit vector that points in that direction.)

Comment: @littleO I thought if a vector has a value 2 then it can't be parallel to a vector of value 1.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a vector of value 2?

Comment: A vector is a unit vector if it has length $1$, regardless of its direction. Take any unit vector $u$, and scale it by a factor of $2$, yielding $v=2u$. Then $u,v$ are in the same direction (hence also parallel), and $v$ has length $2$. Conversely, if $v$ is any vector of length $2$, then the vector $u=\frac{1}{2}v$ is a unit vector, and $u,v$ are in the same direction (hence also parallel).

Comment: Oh thanks quasi, I get it now

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a non-unit vector. Set $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{u}/|\mathbf{u}|$. Then $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector and $\mathbf{u}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{n}$ since $\mathbf{u} = |\mathbf{u}| \, \mathbf{n}.$

Answer (score 0):

A vector doesn't have "a value 2". It has a length and a direction. Vectors are parallel if they have the same direction. The length doesn't matter. A vector is a unit vector if its length is 1. The direction doesn't matter.

So to find a unit vector parallel to some other vector, you need it to point in the same direction, and to have length 1.